# the click function is not working on page load

Tags: jquery

It is not working on page loading. but on button click it is working good

pls give the sollution

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
 $("ul#phaseTab li:first-child a").trigger('click');
    $('#phaseTab').on('click','li', function () {
        if (tabIndex != $(this).index()&&rowdata!=null)
        {
            restoreRow(phaseTable, rowdata, nEditing);``

        }
        tabIndex = $(this).index();
        for (var i = 6; i <= columnCount-2; i++) {

            if (i >= 6 + tabIndex * 5 && i < 6 + (tabIndex + 1) * 5) {
                phaseTable.columns(i).visible(true);
            }
            else {
                phaseTable.columns(i).visible(false);
            }
        }

    });

});
```

Comment: You are triggering a click element on an A-Tag not on the li-Element where u definied your Clickhandler

Comment: Place `$("ul#phaseTab li:first-child a").trigger('click');` after your `.on(...)` function and change the initial one to `$("ul#phaseTab li:first-child a").click();`

Answer (score 0):

Wrong click element or wrong eventListener.

You click on anchor at the page load. But your event listener is on li element.